# How do i implement Angular2 clock

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, rxjs

i tried implementing angular2 clock using server timestamp but got strucked. the second code return a static dateTime

```
this.clock = Observable.interval(1000).map(()=> new Date());

{{clock | async | date:'medium'}}
```

this does update per sec, works well

```
this.clock = Observable.interval(1000).map(()=> new Date(1512151753372));

{{clock | async | date:'medium'}}
```

this does not update at all

1512151753372 is the timestamp provided by the server

Any Idea Please??

Comment: If you want to use the second example code, you need a mechanism to update the server timestamp on a regular basis. As written, it (1512151753372) is a static number, and it will not be updated.

Comment: i cant query the server per sec, i want is to get the current timestamp from the server then the client time can start from the last requested server timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 1 (don't do this...)

You could seed the `.scan` operator seeded with the date from the server and increment it every second like this:

```js
Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
 .scan(function (acc, x) {
    return new Date(acc.getTime() + 1000);
  }, new Date(1512151753372))
  .subscribe(x => { console.log(x); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

This will eventually drift because it wont exactly run every second. It also doesn't account for anomalies like DST.

#### Option 2

This would probably be more accurate but you have to do a little work outside or rxjs to scope some variables:

```js
const server = 1512151753372;
const now = Date.now();
Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .map(x => new Date(server + Date.now() - now))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

This should avoid the drift issue in #1 but you should still get a fresh timestamp from the server every 15 min to avoid DST issues. The only drift that should occur is between when you got the timestamp from the server and when you seed it with Date.now().

Note that if the client changes their system clock then it will probably throw off your clock till you sync with the server again.

Comment: i'm working on app examination app such that the duration(time) is determined by the server.. unfortunately, i cannot keep querying the server for time per sec. i can only query the server to know the current time then let the client time start from there

Comment: @netx Are you doing a countdown?

Comment: great that consider server time instead of client time